# Missing Scaffolders ASP.Net Core

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Traditionally there used to be scaffolding in Visual Studio to speed up adding controllers, areas, views, etc. After I installed ASP.NET Core, I noticed that all of these are gone, and this terrible (especially when you want to add a new area, it will be a terrible pain in the neck to manually do the job).

Is there any possible way to bring them back? Why would Microsoft team make such terrible decision?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any possible way to bring them back?

You need to add the necessary packages:

- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools`
- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc`

Here is an example project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After adding those packages, you will have access to the scaffolding.

[image]

For reference, the above screenshot is from Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with these relevant extensions:

- Microsoft .NET Core Tools
- Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools

Comment: You still have to add it to the tools section otherwise the UI won't find the command line tools

Comment: How to do this now in Visual Studio 2017 RC (with asp.net core 1.1) when there is no project.json. This doesn't work for me :-(.

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc` dint work for me, but I still was able to get the option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On [Getting started with ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework Core using
Visual Studio (1 of 10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) intro of ASP.NET there are explicit written:

> Don't miss setting authentication to Individual User Accounts. You
>   won't be using authentication in this tutorial, but you need to enable
>   it because of a limitation of .NET Core Preview 2 Visual Studio
>   tooling. **Scaffolding for MVC controllers and views only works when
>   Individual User Accounts authentication is enabled**.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the project for scaffolding

**Add the following highlighted NuGet packages to the YourProject.csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Save the file and select Rebuild Project**